# link to a resource outside your app laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, hyperlink

No one seems to hit this problem, as there no questions on it online.

When i do something like

```
<a href="{{ $client->client_url }}" class="btn  btn-default">Go back to {{ $client->client_name }} homepage></a>
```

Laravel istead of taking the user to say

```
http://www.client_website.com
```

it does something like

```
http://myApp/http://www.client_website.com
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must be saving `client_url` as full URL. I.e: `http://www.client_url.com`

So this way it will not append to your url. but rather open client url.

And one suggestion: Add _target="blank" to your `<a>` tag, this open new tab instead of loading on the same tab and override your own site.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<a
    href="http://www.{{ $client->client_url }}"
    class="btn btn-default"
    target="_blank" <!-- If you want to open the external page in a new tab/window -->
>
    Go back to {{ $client->client_name }} homepage
</a>
```

Also you can save the full `URL` (including `http://www.`) in database when saving it and just use `href="{{ $client->client_url }}"` as suggested in other answer.